# How to /summon an item riding a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone help me with it? I know there's a way to summon mobs, of course, also items, but can you stack them together so the item is on top? I found no way to do it, perhaps i just do something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Passengers` list tag will hold a list of entities that are riding the host entity:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},PickupDelay:32767s}]}
```

Being a list, you can have multiple entities riding at the same depth (which is used for boats to carry multiple passengers):

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Creeper"},{id:"Skeleton"}]}
```

You can also add the `Passengers` list to a passenger, such that they have their own passengers higher up:

```
/summon Boat ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Creeper"},{id:"Skeleton",Passengers:[{id:"Zombie"}]}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but can the item not be collectable?

Comment: @TacoBurrito Yep, if you set `PickupDelay` to 32767, the value will not decrease at all and can never be picked up as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Wood block riding on an Ocelot:

```
/summon minecraft:ocelot ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Falling_block",Time:1,TileID:162,Data:16}]}
```

If you want the block to move around on its own use this:

```
/summon minecraft:ocelot ~ ~1 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:2000000,Ambient:1,ShowParticles:0b}],Passengers:[{id:"Falling_block",Time:1,TileID:162,Data:16}]}
```

Enjoy and have fun!